# Pattern Matching or Fuzzy Matching of two tables based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming I have the right naming, what O am trying to write is a function or stored procedure to compare names and find out if they are the same value.

I think its called fuzzy matching

For example, a table has 2 columns and table b has 3 columns:

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | 24 |
| Evening | 56 |

| Name | Num | F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Heello | 23 | some value |
| GoodEvening | 15 | some value |

I want table like

| A | D |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | Heello |
| Morning | GoodMorning |

Currently, I'm using

```
Select A.Name, B.Name
from table A
left  table B
on A.Name like B.Name
or (LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( A.Name,' ',''),'-',''),'''',''))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.Name,' ',''),'-',''),'''','')))) 
 OR (A.Name LIKE '%'+B.Name+'%') 
        OR (B.Name LIKE '%'+A.Name+'%')
```

It is giving me a result, but not too accurate and is very slow, any other way I could try to compare these values?

Comment: There's no way to speed this up: `OR (A.Name LIKE '%'+B.Name+'%') OR (B.Name LIKE '%'+A.Name+'%')` - that's going to have to scan _every single row_ (multiple times!) so will become more and more expensive as the tables get larger.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand for replying, is there any method or way I could do this pattern matching?